# How to set a variable while switching tabs in ttk notebook

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I wanted to set a variable value based on tab switching in `tkk:notebook`. Is there any options that can help me to achieve this?

I wanted to keep flag as 0 for default tab, and when user switches another tab make it flag as 1.

Here is my code, but didn't helped me:

```
ttk::notebook .top.d -padding 5
ttk::frame .top.d.f1;
ttk::frame .top.d.f2;
.top.d add .top.d.f2 -text "Tab A" -padding 5
.top.d add .top.d.f1 -text "TAB B" -padding 5
.top.d select .top.d.f1
ttk::notebook::enableTraversal .top.d
if {.top.d select .top.d.f2 } {
    set flag 2
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you are trying to get the index of the current tab, and if that's so, then you can use:

```
.top.d index current
```

To get the index of the tab at any point in time (index is 0 based).

---

But if you really want to change the value of a variable upon tab change, you can use the virtual event `<<NotebookTabChanged>>`:

```
bind .top.d <<NotebookTabChanged>> {
    if {[.top.d select] == ".top.d.f2"} {set flag 2}
}
```

Everything above is on the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm).

Comment: Thanks Jerry, i completely missed the virtual event section.